# Assigning privileges like CREATE USER, CREATE ROLE, SHOW DB and dynamic privileges using GRANT

Tags: mysql, privileges

I want to assign the privileges CREATE USER, CREATE ROLE, SHOW DB and other dynamic privileges to users in Mysql. How do I do these assignments? Is there any way I can use GRANT for the same.

Comment: You use [`GRANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-overview)

Comment: Could you please give me the syntax for assigning only CREATE USER privilege to a user. I have been digging around for quite sometime but haven'e been able to find the same.

Comment: Never Mind. I just figured out my mistake ! Thanks @gview